# Will I still have to buy the amiibo update in animal crossing new leaf if I restart

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

After finding out that the amiibo update had to be brought at the e-shop it was sad I have no idea how it works and I can't even ask for permisson to use the e-shop becouse I already know it would be a NO

So I only have these options 
1. Delete my whole save on animal crossing new leaf (start from scratch)(the game is mine btw)
Or
2. Buy a new game card/cartridge and still have my old town on the other (this option is least likely to happen)

But first I need to know if it's worth it so if I delete my whole save file or buy a new game card/cartridge will I still have to buy the amiibo update?
(I don't have any friends registered)

And if it matters I never deleted my save on animal crossing (but I know how) and I started my town on the Christmas on the year the game came out

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Are you asking if purchasing a new cartridge will contain the amiibo update for free?  Do you think erasing your whole game file will make the update appear for free?  Why is buying a new cartridge a more likely option than buying the update in the e-shop?  ("least likely" vs "I already know it will be NO")

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the amiibo update is to either create a Nintendo Network ID to be able to download it for free on the Nintendo eShop, or, buy a retail copy of *Animal Crossing: New Leaf - Welcome amiibo*. Deleting your save and starting over isn't going to do anything.

Seeing as how the update is free, if you kindly ask your parent/guardian to allow you to make a NNID and download it they hopefully should say yes. If that's not possible, you can always create a NNID with a fake email and just disable the account after you've downloaded the update. Note that you do need internet access.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score -2):

No. You should never restart your game because you'll lose everything, but if you do, the game cardrage will forever be updated. Sadly if you buy a new game, it might not be updated, so ask the person your buying from to give you the 2017 model.

Comment: An update through the app store isn't tied to the cartridge; it's tied to the Nintendo ID.